# Strong countinuous and locally bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $S$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Suppose that $T: S\to B(X)$ is strongly continuous ( that is for each $x\in X$, the map $s \to T(s)x :S\to X$ is continuous). Prove that $T$ is locally bounded, that is prove that for any compact $K\subset S$,$\sup \{\|T(s)\|: s\in K\}<\infty$,where $\|T(s)\|$ denotes the norm of the bounded operator $T(s)$ for all $s\in S$.

---

What I think is using some topology knowledge to prove it ,form example for fix $x$ ,$T(K)x$ is compact set,$X$ is Hausdorff space, so $T(K)x$ is also a closed set, I also know a continuous function on a compact set has extreme value,however I still feel I ignore something so that I cannot solve this problem.

Comment: Have you heard of Mssrs. Banach et Steinhaus?

Comment: @DanielFischer No, I have not heard that.

Comment: Them. Two famous Polish mathematicians. Together immortalized in the incredibly useful Banach-Steinhaus theorem.